# Java is not taking user input for the first variable

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NoteIt {
    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Answer;
        int i=2;

        System.out.print("\nPlease Enter your Name: ");
        String Name = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Welcome to Note-It "+Name+", We hope you'll enjoy our application. ");

        String[][] Main = new String[2][2];

        Main[0][0]="Create new Note";
        Main[1][0]="View My Notes";

        System.out.println("\nPlease select what to do: \n");

        for(int n=0; n<2; n++){
            System.out.println((n+1)+") "+Main[n][0]);
        }
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter your response: ");
        Answer = s.nextInt();

        if(Answer == 1){
            i++;
            Main = new String[i][2];
            System.out.print("\nTitle: ");
            Main[i-1][0]=s.nextLine();
            System.out.print("\nBody: ");
            Main[i-1][1]=s.nextLine();
        }

    }
}
```

I don't know why it is not asking for Title?

Comment: what is it doing? what values do you enter? Could you please follow naming conventions? Your code is quite difficult to follow. Do you know the difference between 'nextInt()' and 'nextLine()' ?

Comment: try only Main[i-1][0]=s.next();

Comment: @Coder1 that won't change the fact that nextInt doesn't take a break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Rohit Jain, That's because the Scanner.nextInt method does not read the newline character in your input created by hitting "Enter," and so the call to Scanner.nextLine returns after reading that newline.

Description here: [check this question too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Try this it may help...

```
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int Answer;
    int i=2;

    System.out.print("\nPlease Enter your Name: ");
    String Name = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Welcome to Note-It "+Name+", We hope you'll enjoy our application. ");

    String[][] Main = new String[2][2];

    Main[0][0]="Create new Note";
    Main[1][0]="View My Notes";

    System.out.println("\nPlease select what to do: \n");

    for(int n=0; n<2; n++){
        System.out.println((n+1)+") "+Main[n][0]);
    }
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter your response: ");
    Answer = s.nextInt();

    if(Answer == 1){
        i++;
        Main = new String[i][2];
        System.out.print("\nTitle: ");
        Main[i-1][0]=s.next();
        System.out.print("\nBody: ");
        Main[i-1][1]=s.next();
    }
```

Comment: Mind sharing what you changed and why? It's hard to spot the differences.

Comment: These two lines ====>  Main[i-1][0]=s.next();  ========>  Main[i-1][1]=s.next(); & its working fine.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to make that clear. It is also helpful to explain why this is working fine.

Comment: Honestly I don't know but I used this trick, If you or anyone know please explain